# Custom xlabels in plotly express bar chart

Tags: plotly, bar-chart

I have following dataframe:

```
data = {'make' : ['Audi', 'Audi', 'BMW', 'Mercedes', 'Mercedes'],
       'model':["A4", "R8", "M4", "AMG GT", "SLS"],
       'REF':['GT2', 'GT3', 'GT4', 'GT5','GT6'],
       'weight':[1460, 1260, 1280, 1800, 1600]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

and I need to plot the weight for each vehicle as a bar chart in plotly express.

```
fig = px.bar(
    df,
    x='REF', 
    y='weight',
    barmode='group',
    template = "plotly_dark",
    text="final weight")
```

Now, I would like to change the automatic xlabels (GT2, GT3, etc) by concatenating columns make and model to have instead of GT2 -> Audi A4

Any suggestions how I can achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: The following answer is one way to do this, but it is also possible to use Graph Update to update the x-axis tick labels in a batch. `fig.update_traces(x=[x[0]+' '+x[1] for x in df[['make','model']].values])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use `update_xaxes`:

```
fig.update_xaxes(tickangle = -45,
                 tickmode = 'array',
                 tickvals = list(range(len(df))),
                 ticktext = df['make'] + ' ' + df['model'])
```

Output:

[image]

EDIT:

Better idea:

> The following answer is one way to do this, but it is also possible to use Graph Update to update the x-axis tick labels in a batch. `fig.update_traces(x=[x[0]+' '+x[1] for x in df[['make','model']].values])` - [r-beginners](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13107804/r-beginners) Apr 27 at 0:16